# Common API for ESX, Hyper-V, Virtual Server?

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, esx

ESX, Hyper-V, and Virtual Server all have their own, non-interoperable APIs. Do you know of any library that unifies these?

Thanks, J.

Answer (score 1):

The only API I know that can interact across the product borders is the PowerShell interface of Microsofts "System Center Virtual Machine Manager".

Requirements:
1. Buy MS SCVMM
2. In order to automate VMWare ESX with SCVMM you have to use the Virtual Center AddOn

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen anything like an entirely hypervisor-agnostic API library. However, you can get decent hypervisor coverage starting with [libvirt](http://libvirt.org/), which covers most *nix-based virtualization. That just leaves Hyper-V out, for which you can use the [WMI APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc136992%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or SCVMM as Mischa recommends.